# "-6: Not Supported" error when transferring files from phone to external HDD

Tags: usb-drive

I am trying to transfer files from my phone to my external HDD. Both are plugged into the computer running Ubuntu 12.04. I am getting a message saying "Error while copying "Ubuntu Made Easy, 5th Edition.pdf". There was an error copying the file into /media/UNTITLED/Documents/Computer Science/C/C in a Nutshell (2006). Error getting file: -6: Not Supported". I have tried drag and drop, cutting the file and pasting into the folder and the option to copy to desktop. I get the same message when trying to transfer from phone to desktop. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is that really the *complete* error message you get? I think it comes with a bit more. Please provide the full message (either copy&paste if text or upload a screenshot somewhere and link it in your question) to share what you actually see on your screen. (so please **edit** your question to include it all) And while you're at it, include some more specific steps prior to the error.

Comment: What filesystem is your external hard drive formatted as? I believe you're trying to copy a file with a filename not supported on the target. Try to rename it to something without special characters (only A-Z, a-z, 0-9) and try again.

Comment: I got the same error "Error getting file: -6: Not Supported" while copying *.docx file from Xperia phone to ubuntu 12.04 machine.Phone is connected in "Media Transfer Mode"(MTP). Machine's file system is "Ext4 journaling file system". Followed this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_trEVXBgLg to install ubuntu.

Comment: Note: Copying works, If I connect phone in "Mass Storage Mode". Any idea why it is happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (14.04 and Nexus 7 2012 with CM11)
Got to storage-settings and tap on the 3 dots on the upper right, now on the USB- settings.
My Nexus was marked as "Camera (PTP)".

After Changing to "Media Device (MTP)" I gained Access to the whole file system (not just the folders "DCIM" and "Camera") and copying non-media-files worked (tested with *.7z, *.docx, *.txt and *.exe)